# NodeJs / Koa - Error payload not defined inside unit tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, koa

I need help figure out something: I use https://github.com/mjhea0/node-koa-api as a base to develop my API.

In the routes/movies.js file you can see that he uses :

```
router.get(`${BASE_URL}/:id`, async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const movie = await queries.getSingleMovie(ctx.params.id);
    if (movie.length) {
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'success',
        data: movie
      };
    } else {
      ctx.status = 404;
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'error',
        message: 'That movie does not exist.'
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

To make the GET /movies/id route and inside unit tests :

```
describe('GET /api/v1/movies/:id', () => {
  it('should throw an error if the movie does not exist', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/api/v1/movies/9999999')
    .end((err, res) => {
      // there should an error
      should.exist(err);
      // there should be a 404 status code
      res.status.should.equal(404);
      // the response should be JSON
      res.type.should.equal('application/json');
      // the JSON response body should have a
      // key-value pair of {"status": "error"}
      res.body.status.should.eql('error');
      // the JSON response body should have a
      // key-value pair of {"message": "That movie does not exist."}
      res.body.message.should.eql('That movie does not exist.');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

To test for the wrong id.

I have the exact same code in my router but for my own entity 'guilds' :

```
router.get('/api/v1/guilds/:id', async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const guild = await queries.getOneGuild(ctx.params.id);
    if (guild.length) {
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'success',
        data: guild,
      };
    } else {
      ctx.status = 404;
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'error',
        message: 'That guild does not exist.',
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

And inside my tests/routes.guilds.test.js is the same as the referenced github repo :

```
describe('GET /api/v1/guilds/:id', () => {
  it('should throw an error if the guild does not exist', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
     .get('/api/v1/guilds/9999999')
     .end((err, res) => {
       console.log(err);
       should.exist(err);
       // there should be a 404 status code
       res.status.should.equal(404);
       // the response should be JSON
       res.type.should.equal('application/json');
       // the JSON response body should have a
       // key-value pair of {"status": "error"}
       res.body.status.should.eql('error');
       // the JSON response body should have a
       // key-value pair of {"message": "That guild does not exist."}
       res.body.message.should.eql('That guild does not exist.');
       done();
     });
  });
});
```

My problem is that line :

```
// there should an error
should.exist(err);
```

In the referenced GitHub: err is set to a value, while in my code err is undefined ...

I don't understand why the referenced GitHub code as the err set to a big array of data in

```
.end((err, res) => {})
```

And mine isn't even defined. Especially since I do the same stuff...

It's my first Koa / Node.js API so that I might have just missed something.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Edit: Forgot to say that.

```
ctx.status = 404;
ctx.body = {
  status: 'error',
  message: 'Guild not found.'
};
```

actually works and I can see their values in Mocha's Unit-Tests :

```
.end((err, res) => {
  console.log(res.status); // Prints 404
  console.log(res.body.message); // Prints 'Guild not found'
});
```

Its seems Koa / Koa-router inside the referenced Github repo automatically sees it as an error and sets something while in my code it doesn't...

Edit 2: Because of the first answer is given, I tested to remove the try catch block inside the referenced GitHub source code, and their unit test still works so it has nothing to do with the try catch block.

```
router.get(`${BASE_URL}/:id`, async (ctx) => {
  const movie = await queries.getSingleMovie(ctx.params.id);
  if (movie.length) {
     ctx.body = {
       status: 'success',
       data: movie
     };
   } else {
     ctx.status = 404;
     ctx.body = {
       status: 'error',
       message: 'That movie does not exist.'
     };
   }
});
```

as the same behavior regarding the unit-tests: Err is still set inside `routes.movies.test.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, this github repo uses chai-http@3.0.0 and i was using chai-http@4.2.0

in chai-http@4.0.0 they removed the err argument if the request is successful.

Issue was solved by just keeping chai-http@4.2.0 and removing `should.exists(err)`

Thanks to : https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1855